# (VBA) Putting ComboBox + macroevent on cell change

Tags: vba, events, combobox, cell

I'm trying to put a combobox inside active worksheet (but not activeX combobox), choose a list to fill and linked cell. It is an easy task, for example:

```
Sub make_combobox()

ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(69.75, 1.5, 79.5, 40.5).Select
Selection.Name = "combo"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("combo").Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = "$A$1:$A$3"
    .LinkedCell = "$D$1"
    .DropDownLines = 8
    .Display3DShading = False
End With

End Sub
```

I tried to put macro in worksheet containing this combobox, which will show msgbox whenever chosen linked cell is changed according to the chosen option in combobox. I wrote this in Worksheet section:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "It works!"
End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work (Actually, it works when I change a value in D1 manually, but not work as a result of change in combobox).

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a macro to the control using the `OnAction` property. It will run after every change made to the Combobox's value.

Comment: Thank you! Bu I'm still wondering why it doesn't treat a change in a linked cell as an impulse to execute the macro.

Comment: I don't think you will get a clear answer on this one. The event handler is fired when an event occurs. Apparently Excel developers decided that such an event is not raised when a cell value gets updated through a Combobox change. The reason for this, which I see as a viable one, is that you have the `Combobox_Change` event handler to take care of this. If you could use both, then you might "duplicate" an event, and I can't imagine such an outcome to be desirable.